# Override directly paintComponent from JComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, extends, jcomponent

I have a little problem about using `super.paintComponent(g);`.
I'm using 2 classes A which extends JPanel and B which extends A as follow :

```
public class A extends JPanel {
...
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // code of A
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A {
...
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // code of B
}
```

My problem here is that when an object of B calls `paintComponent(g);`, it also calls the super which is the function of A and then executes a code that I don't want.
How can I directly call the `paintComponent(g);` of `JComponent` without calling the overriden fonction of A ?

**EDIT** : A is not abstract so I can instanciate an object of it.
**EDIT2 :** : Here is an easy example which is pretty similar with my problem :

```
public class Polygon2 extends Polygon {

    private boolean isClicked;
    ...
    public void setClicked(boolean clicked){
        isClicked = clicked;
    }
    public boolean isClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }
}

public class A extends JPanel {

    protected Polygon2 polygon;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }
}


public class B extends A implements MouseListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()) { // click on the polygon
            polygon.setClicked(true);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        polygon.setClicked(false);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (polygon.isClicked()) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending `A` if you don't want `A`'s behavior?

Comment: How about removing `super.paintComponent(g);` since you don't want A's `paintComponent()` method to be executed?

Comment: B is an extension of A, but its `paintComponent(g);` is redundant because I draw something more in B. And B needs A's variables and functions to work. The problem is just the draw part.

Comment: Is it useless to call `paintComponent(g);` of JComponent ?

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work as you expect it. @JBNizet careful - not calling super might violate the component's opaqueness contract.

Answer (score 2):

You would extract one or more methods that could be overridden by subclasses, something like:

```
public class A extends JPanel {

    protected Polygon2 polygon;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        configureGraphics(g);
        g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }

    protected void configureGraphics(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void configureGraphics(Graphics g) {
        if (polygon.isClicked()) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
    }

}
```

BTW, a general rule is to not expose public methods that are not meant to be used publicly: here that translates to let B use a mouseListener (vs. implementing it).